# Imprimir variable con salto de linea

Tags: python-3.x, print

Buenos días tengo un archivo de python con varias cadenas de texto y las necesito imprimir en mi archivo principal.

textos.py

```
texto1='Texto para la primer página del archivo\nIntroduccion...'
texto2='.....'
...
```

Archivo principal

```
from textos import *

print(texto1)
```

Esto me da como resultado:

```
Texto para la primer página del archivo
```

Que necesito hacer para que imprima lo que va después del salto de linea?

Saludos y gracias de antemano

Comment: No veo el error: el texto se imprime correctamente en dos líneas separadas.

Comment: No necesitas hacer nada. Tal como lo tienes debería salir "Introducción" debajo de "Texto para la..." ¿Lo estás imprimiendo por pantalla o lo estás redirigiendo a un fichero? ¿Con qué sistema operativo estás trabajando? ¿Lo ejecutas en una consola o dentro de un IDE? Estos factores podrían ser relevantes